# Google Analytics Custom Identifier

Tags: variables, google-analytics

Hi I'm investigating Google analytics. What I'd like to do is add a custom tracking variable, i.e. a GUID which relates to our ecommerce system. Ideally I'd like to use use the data export API to pull the data back into our systems and do some reporting. Google specifically prohibits personally identifiable data like an email address being used, but what about a GUID that only our ecommerce systems. Is what I want to do possible and is it with the terms of Google's conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Google not only prohibits direct personally identifiable data, but it also prohibits data that can be used to indirectly personally identify people within your own system.  So in other words, if that GUID is attached to a personally identifiable info within your own system, you cannot send that data to GA, because you can easily export the GA data, tie it back into your system, and attribute GA data to personally identifiable data.

Of course, someone would have to bring it to google's attention, and someone would have to prove there is a link to said data...

Comment: What if I did the other way around, and passed in custom variables for very general demographic data such as gender and age range e.g 25-40 etc. I would assume if I pulled that data back into my ecommerce system it would be sufficiently anonymized.

Comment: I think if you're going to play "what if" games you should probably ask a lawyer!